# countForFetchRequest returning 1 for empty table

Tags: ios, core-data

I am executing a 'countForFetchRequest' and it is always returning 1 more count than the number of records in my table.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TESTDATA" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(count == NSNotFound) {
    // Handle error
}

return count;
```

That returns 1 when my table is empty.  Returns 4 if my table has 3 rows.

```
sqlite> select count(*) from ZTESTDATA;
0
sqlite>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have all objects been saved?

Comment: Have you tried removing all objects directly before getting the entity's count?

Comment: @Kraken, yes I remove all (actually remove the database and recreate), then count comes back as zero.  I then relaunch the app and the count is one more than it should be.  Regardless the raw sql query I perform always has the right count, seems like my core data query is messed up.

Comment: You should try a fetch request and see what object is there in the database. Maybe one of your query inserted something and you didn't noticed.

Comment: You really shouldn't be looking at a core data SQLite file directly with the SQLite tools.  Try executing that fetch request to see what this extra object is.

Comment: Are you able to open the db directly and browse it with **SQLite Database Browser**? To reach your app navigate to *~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count is always accurate but it counts both what is in memory (not saved yet) and what is on disk.

As others have suggested, do a fetch instead of a count and print out what Core Data finds and you will find your answer.

Comment: I think fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false will do the work