# Core data - countforfetch always returns 1 for empty database

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5.1

I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845543/countforfetchrequest-returning-1-for-empty-table) where countforfetch is always 1. But doesn't give the solution.

When i do a fetch request as given in the link it gives me the data i was about to save every time. So since its already present it wont re-save. So the database is empty. But surprisingly the data comes on the table.

This seems like a very weird behaviour. Can some please help ?

here is my code

```
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest12 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderNumber = %@",orderList.orderNumber];
    [fetchRequest12 setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest12 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrderList" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext]];
      NSLog(@"The fetch was successful! %@", [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest12 error:&error]);

    if ([appDelegate.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest12 error:&error] ==0 ) { // Somethings to be done 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `setIncludesPendingChanges:` to `NO` if you want the fetch request to ignore any changes that you have made in the MOC but not yet saved. By default all unsaved changes are fetched (hence you see unsaved changes displayed in your UI).